# Dynamic method name inside a class?

Tags: php, wordpress, oop, methods

I'd like to, when instantiating a class to be able to pass to it a name that will be used for prefixing a method name in that class, so far I have this

```
<?php
if ( ! class_exists( 'My_Class' ) ) {
    /**
     * Creates filter method
     *
     * @since  1.0.0
     */
    class My_Class {

        /**
         * Prefix for method names
         *
         * @var string $name Name of the filter prefix.
         */
        private $name;

        /**
         * Version.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        private $version = '1.0.0';

        /**
         * Initialize the class and set its properties.
         *
         * @since 1.0.0
         * @param string $name    The name for the method prefix.
         * @param string $version The version of this plugin.
         */
        public function __construct( $name, $version ) {
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->version = $version;
            add_filter( 'my_filter_name', $name . '_my_folder' );
        }

        /**
         * Function for filtering folder array
         *
         * Each plugin has to set its own array of paths and url.
         *
         * @param  array $import_array Array with folder values.
         * @return array               Modified array with folder values.
         */
        public function $name . _my_folder() {
            $import_array[$this->name]['folder']     = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/layout';
            $import_array[$this->name]['folder_url'] = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/layout';
            return $import_array;
        }

    }
}
```

The idea is that I'd just call it like

```
$first_object = new My_Class( 'first' );
$second_object = new My_Class( 'second' );
```

This is so that I can use this in multiple same plugins, with different names, depending on the type of the plugin.

The obvious problem is `function $name . _my_folder()`.

I read something about `__call()` magic method but I'm not sure if this can be used in this case, or how to apply it.

Can this be done?

Comment: Why do you need this? It is absolutely bad idea to use it like this. It seems like bad OOP design. Please describe your use-case for this.

Comment: In WordPress you can use filters to modify the workings of a function if it has the `apply_filters` function in it. I need to be able to append to existing array, array with all the plugin urls (same looking plugins, with different import files). For that I can manually write functions and adding them to filter, which is long and tedious task if there are many such plugins, so my idea is to just create an object that will do this for me, since only the prefix name of the function used for filter changes (and array key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you make name parameter of the method?

Like this:

```
add_filter('my_filter_name', [$this, 'methodName'], 10, 1);
```

third parameter is priority of filter, and fourth is number of accepted args.

```
public function methodName($name) {}
```

and call it like this:

```
apply_filters('my_filter_name', $value, $arg);
```

Comment: I'll see if this will work. In theory it should, I've done this before, don't know why I haven't used this in the first place. Thanks

Comment: Otherwise you can use magic `__call($name, $args)` method but parameter is better solution.

Comment: With some modifications this works, but the `plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )` always points to one of the 2 plugins. It registers two plugins, and the array is filled with 2 arrays which is great (the name is correctly passed in the array), but the path is the same in both cases...

Comment: Which makes sense since I defined class in the first plugin, so it's used to create an instance in the second case with the same dir path... I'll have to add this as an argument as well. I'm dumb xD

Comment: exactly, pass the file path as next arg

Comment: The funny thing is that I've used this numerous times, don't know why I didn't remember it lol Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not an expert, but I think that you have to specific the default version in the constructor... I'm not sure, but you can try it.

```
    public function __construct( $name, $version="1.0.0" ) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->version = $version;
        add_filter( 'my_filter_name', $name . '_my_folder' );
    }
```